# Octave: How to vectorize a Fourier series function?

Tags: vectorization, octave

Let's say I have a composite signal; with a Fourier analysis I found the coefficients for the cosine (a) and sine (b) terms and I put them in a matrix together with frequencies in Hz. Using a `for` cycle to compute the Fourier series from coefficients and frequencies, I have the expected results.

```
%Startcode
t = linspace(1,5,100)';
a0 = 0;
a = [1;3;0;0];
b = [0;0;4;2];
w = [1;10;20;30];
C = [a,b,w];
k = length(w);
fs = a0 .* ones(length(t),1);
for j=1:k
    fs = fs + C(j,1)*cos(2*pi*C(j,3)*t) + C(j,2)*sin(2*pi*C(j,3)*t);
end
plot(t,fs);
%Endcode
```

However, I would like to vectorize the code in order to eliminate the `for` cycle. Any suggestions?

UDATE: The code should me modified thus:

```
t = linspace(1,5,200)';
```

Because with only 100 intervals aliasing occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the result which is within cosines and sines with normal matrix multiplication after [transposing](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html#XREFtranspose) `t`. Multiplying it with columns of `C` can be done with implicit expansion (`.*`) and then just [`sum`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Sums-and-Products.html#XREFsum) along the rows.

```
fs = a0 + sum( C(:,1).*cos(2*pi*C(:,3)*t.')  +  C(:,2).*sin(2*pi*C(:,3)*t.') );
```

Comment: Is ".  *t'"  same as "*t.'"?

Comment: @Fabio No, these are different operators. `.'` takes transpose. Simple`'` takes complex conjugate transpose. `.*` means element-wise multiplication or multiplication through implicit expansion (depends on the situation). `*` is for the usual matrix multiplication

Comment: Alright, thanks. I tested the vectorialized code as you suggested and it works. The only difference is that I put time values in a row vector from the start, instead of transposing a column vector.

Comment: @Fabio Yes you can definitely do that if you don't really need a column vector at the start. I strictly focused on vectorising your loop